# Two way scroll view (diagonally) like in android Google Sheets app

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, scroll

I wonder how to implement two way scroll view (diagonally) like in android Google Sheets app:
[screen](http://imageshack.com/a/img538/3464/AYNACE.png)

This component allows to scroll content on any direction.

Maybe exist similar component alredy?
If no exist similar component, maybe someone give any advice how to implement that component?

This view also must meet the requirements:

- recycle children views (like ListView or GridView)
- children views (cells) can have different width (for example like on
  [picture](http://imageshack.com/a/img537/1509/RnqAeX.png))

Best Regards

trebor

Comment: Maybe Android's documentation regarding Draging&Scaling/Drag&Drop could help https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/scale.html

Comment: @shkschneider  I do not see how Draging&Scaling/Drag&Drop can help to implement two way scroll component with recycled views.

Comment: The "diagonal scroll view like in Google Sheets", to me, is a drag. But I don't know how they did it. It was just an humble lead. Good luck!